# SQL Sever and JAVA website connection JDBC

Tags: sql-server, jsp, servlets, jdbc, web

I have created a JAVA application that connects to a SQL server database. 
I used  'Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server' to connect my application to the database.
I included the 'sqljdbc4.jar' file in my PC Classpath and in my Java Application Library, a made other nessa there after in connected perfectly.

i am now making a local website similar to this Java Application, with basically the same features, the problem i an having is, i cannot connect the database to my website as i did with the Java application. it constantly says "No suitable driver found". my JAVA Application still runs, but not the website, even though in using the same PC, and the driver is still included in my PC Class path and Website library.

You can have a look at my code that i have attached.
i have also tried connecting using a servlet rather than a jsp page but it gives me the same issue.

Could you please guide me as to what i am doing wrong, and if possible show me the correct way to connect my Webpage to the SQL Server database i created.

PS - I used to connect to SQL Sever to my websites using a JDBC ODBC Bridge, but now that doesn't work.

My Code -

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Test Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<p>
    <b>
        Test Page
    </b>
</p>

<%
try
{                    
    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=Test;user=admin;password=admin";
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement("Insert Into Test (UserName, Password ) Values ('Test_UName', 'Test_password')");  
    out.println("<BR><TD>Inserted Successful</TD>");
}
catch(Exception e)
{                    
    out.println("<TD>Insert not Successful</TD>");        
    out.println("<BR><TD>" + e + "</TD>");
}

%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hey guys, thank you so much for your help, i figured out the problem. I ran the very same code on another PC and it worked perfectly. so the problem is something on the PC not the code. thank you so much once again for you help...

Answer (score 0):

Your Jar file will need to be under your Java SDK installation, under `jre\lib\ext`.  So that you don't have to specify extra classpath info to Tomcat.
Example: `D:\Sun\Java7SDK\jre\lib\ext\`

It may be simply that I'm using a different driver (my jar file is named differently) but you may also be missing the word Microsoft in your connection string:

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://" ...
```

I don't know what version of Java you're using, but in older versions of Java you needed to say what driver you were using before calling `DriverManager.getConnection`, which you would do like:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver");
```

Comment: i put my jar file into the jre\lib\ext folder. but it still giving me the same error, i have also tried changing my connection sting around, in every way that was possible, but it still gave me this error. i dont understand what wrong i am doing...

Answer (score 0):

This is how to connect..

```
    public static void connect() throws Exception {
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tour_package?autoReconnect=true";
     c = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","123");
     //root=database name
     //123= password
}
```

if you want get result set you have to write a method.

Comment: from my understanding this string is to connect to a 'MySQL' database, im using SQL Server, even though, i have made these changes to my code, but it still cannot find the driver, is there any other way to connect SQL Server to a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should add the JDBC sql java library to you project library, then clean build and try to RUN the project.